Autopilot - Intune: Get Hardware-Hashes to Backup
How can I backup devices from Autopilot before deletion?
Once deleted, I would like to be able to undo deletes by re-adding devices.
For this, I need the hardware-hash
But https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/windowsAutopilotDeviceIdentities does not list the 4000byte hardware hash.
Background: As a school, when leaving, students can take their devices with them. Often, they need to attach to a different school's tenant - so the record has to be deleted from out Autopilot first.
To avoid false deletes, I would like to keep a backup, because for us it is only possible to add devices with the hardware-hash.
Extracting from running devices is no option (too complicated).
Does Autopilot not expose the stored HW-Hash anywhere, as it does with the other properties of the devices?

Thank you for posting your question. Based on my research, there isn't any Graph API available where you can fetch the Hardware hash of a device. However, you can extract the Hardware hash information from the device itself directly using a Script when it's enrolled.
Let us know if you have any further questions!
